# What's problem with my code. I am giving a curl post request but data is not showing in respose body of header

Tags: node.js, curl, echo-server

This code is receiving data from curl and suppose to show that data on the header body response. But it's not working. Where am I wrong???

```
const server = http.createServer((req , res) => {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
const { headers, method, url } = req;
let body = [];
req.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  })
req.on('data', (chunk) => {
body.push(chunk);
})
req.on('end', () => {
    body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
});
```

});

Comment: Hi, Can you please add the `curl` command and add more info about what you are trying to activate?

Comment: ' curl --location --request POST 'localhost:3000' \  --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
  --data-raw 'All together now!' '

Comment: this is curl command. I just want to show "All together now!"  in header body response through this command

Comment: What do you mean by `header body response`? There is an HTTP response that is built from headers and body. where do you what the `All together now!` to be set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job if you what `All together now!` to be set in the response body.

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    let body = [];
    req.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(err);
    })
    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body.push(chunk);
    })
    req.on('end', () => {
        body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();

        // set response
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.end(body);
    });
});

server.listen('3000');
```

Comment: @tsm009 please select the answer. Thanks